# Dismiss an add contact view controller from a UIPopover

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Hi In my app I have a button so when you click it a UIPopover comes up with an add contact view in it. It all workers except when you press save. It doesn't Dismiss.

```
-(IBAction) addcontact
{
    ABNewPersonViewController *contacts = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
    // imagePicker.delegate = self;
    // UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contacts];
    UINavigationController *addContactNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:contacts];

    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:addContactNavController];

    popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1000);
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(935, 270, 175, 300) 
                             inView:self.view
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight 
                           animated:YES];
    [popover retain];
    [addContactNavController release];
    [contacts release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate` protocol and assign the delegate in your method above –

```
contacts.newPersonViewDelegate = self;
```

You can then dismiss the popover in the delegate function –

```
- (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonView 
       didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
    [popOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    [popOver release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well,

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
respecively
[popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

should do it?

Edit: to be more concrete:

....

```
  popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:addContactNavController];
  addContactNavController.delegate = self;
```

now on saving, do something like:

```
  -(IBAction) saveStuff {
        ... saving...
        [delegate closePopup];
   }
```

and in your File with -(IBAction) addcontact you do:

```
   -(void) closePopup {
           [self dismissModalViewCotroller...];
   }
```

makes sense?

and yes, you should add a delegate-propery to your controller if not done yet